# Ways to use/integrate an Ethereum - Polygon wallet in an Android app

Tags: dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, android, walletconnect

Where I work, we have an ERC-20 token, running on Polygon Testnet at the moment, and the plan is to to run on the Polygon chain on the future. We have an Android app, where we want to explore ways on how to use/integrate an Ethereum wallet that supports Polygon tokens. Right now I have come accross these 2 options:

[web3j](https://github.com/maticnetwork/web3j)

MetaMask & [WalletConnect](https://docs.walletconnect.org/mobile-linking)

**We want to be able for a user, check in-app his address, his token balance, and (in the future) be able to send outgoing transactions or exchange his token for another crypto.**

We haven't concluded yet if the best way to do it is via 2 seperate applications - ours and MetaMask, and link those two together. Does the web3j library have an option for the user to create a new wallet and have the above functionalities?

Also is there any other library available that we could use to implement what we want? Or do you think using MetaMask and WalletConnect is the industry-standard way to do it at the moment as we aren't 100% sure that we want to build by ourselves a wallet and all its functionality.

Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you in advance.